# Need help to configure CSS template in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am having trouble to configure only css template in codeigniter. e.g: i am beginner in codeigniter. any one can tell me that how can i configure it or any tutorial.
hope you understand my bad English..

here is my code

in view page `home.php`

```
<?php $this->load->view('header_final');?>



     <div id="page">
        <div id="page-bgtop">
            <div id="page-bgbtm">
                <div id="content">
                    <div class="post">
                        <h2 class="title"><a href="#">Home</a></h2><br>

                        <div class="entry">
                            <p><img src="<?=site_url();?>images/img08.jpg" width="538" height="200" alt="" /></p>
                            <p>Sylhet Engineering College (SEC), established in the year 2007 under the School of Applied Science and Technology, Shahjalal University of Science and Technology is best of its kind with a motto to produce the best in class engineers for the 21st century in Bangladesh. There are five universities of Engineering and Technology and some private universities in the country for providing engineering education at B.Sc level which is not sufficient to meet the requirement of today's fast paced engineering sector of Bangladesh. As a divisional city of Bangladesh, Sylhet had no engineering institute. So the Government of Peoples Republic of Bangladesh has established Sylhet Engineering College with a vision to expand the engineering education of Bangladesh as an engineering faculty section of Shahjalal University of Science and Technology.</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="post">


                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <!-- end #content -->


<?php $this->load->view('footer_final');?>
```

In controller page `home.php`

```
<?php

class Home extends Controller {

    function Home()
    {
        parent::Controller();   

    }

    function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('home');


    }
}
```

Hints:

`header_final.php` and `footer-final.php`

Answer (score 3):

CodeIgniter allows you to load multiple views at the same time.  You want to leave your view loads in your controller.  So what you want to do is load the header view in the controller, then load the actual view you want rendered and then load the footer view.  When done it will look something like this:

```
function index(){
    $this->load->view('header_final');
    $this->load->view('home');
    $this->load->view('footer_final');
}
```

Then remove all the view loads from your home.php view.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to use the controller to manipulate your views. Your default controller is specified in the "system/app/config/routes.php" file. The parameters "default_controller" tells the application which controller you want to use by default.

As Carl said, once you have placed all the line of codes you need to load the necessary views, you can point the default_controller to this controller. Note that the function index is the default function used by a controller.

Once you'll go on, you may need to build a custom controller since all of your page are will need this header and footer. I did it by addind a file under "system/app/core/MY_Controller.php"  (Code igniter 2.X, not the same for different version) and I extend this controller instead. The code within this controller looks like this :

```
    <?php

 class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function loadHeader($data = Array(),$customHeader = 'parts/header'){
        $this->load->view($customHeader,$data);
    }
    public function loadFooter($data = Array(),$customFooter = 'parts/footer'){
        $this->load->view($customFooter,$data);
    }
    public function loadSidebar($data = Array(),$customSidebar = 'parts/sidebar'){
        $this->load->view($customSidebar,$data);
    }
}
```

Then from my controller I do something like this :

```
    <?php

class Articles extends MY_Controller {
    public function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * Controller for all news.
     * will be used as home controller.
     */
    public function index() {
        //Needed helper

        //End helper
        $data = Array();
        //Fill the array for the header part
        $data["header"] = Array();
        $data["header"]["title"] = "Articles shelf";
        $data["header"]["logo"] = "David Francoeur";
        $data["header"]["slogan"] = "just a blog about me and knowledge...";
        $this->loadHeader($data["header"]);// I would add a second parameter for a custom header.
        //Fill the array for the rest of the pages
        $data["main"] = Array();
        $this->load->model('Article');
        $data["main"]["query"] = $this->Article->get_last_ten_entries();
        $this->load->view('article', $data["main"]);
        //Fill the array for the right sidebar
        $data["sidebar"] = Array();
        $this->loadSidebar($data["sidebar"]);
        //Fill the array for data concerning the footer
        $data["footer"] = Array();
        $this->loadFooter($data["footer"]);//I would add a second parameter for a custom footer.
    }

}
```

You could also use a single function in your custom controller if you don't need custom header or footer something like :

```
<?php
```

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
public function loadView($data = Array(),$view){
    $this->load->view("header_final");
    $this->load->view($view,$data);
    $this->load->view("footer-final");
}
}
```

It's up to you!